# Javascript code to Jquery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that is changed when I click on several links. The following javascript code works well :

```
<img src="myImage.png" id="mainImg"  /> 

<a href="javascript:;" id="report1_id" onclick="document.getElementById('mainImg').src='http://localhost/convertToReport1.do';">Report1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="report2_id" onclick="document.getElementById('mainImg').src='http://localhost/convertToReport2.do';">Report2</a>
```

But I'm trying to change the code to use Jquery code instead. It calls the same server code as the javascript example. No errors are generated & a png is streamed back. But the image is not updated on the html page. To make things worst, the html moves to the top of the page. In the working javascript code, the image would fresh with a nice ajaxy feel where only the image would change & the rest of the page would not move. My Jquery code is below :

```
<img src="myImage.png" id="mainImg"  /> 

<a href="" id="report1_id">Report1</a>
<a href="" id="report2_id">Report2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        $("#report1_id").click(function(e)     {   
            alert("This Is Report1");
            d = new Date();
            $("#mainImg").attr("src", "http://localhost/convertToReport1.do?"+d.getTime());
        });     

        $("#report2_id").click(function(e)     {   
            alert("This Is Report2");
            d = new Date();
            $("#mainImg").attr("src", "http://localhost/convertToReport2.do?"+d.getTime());
        });             
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are appending a time in the new jQuery code, but not in the old native, inline JS code? Also, you might want to wrap all your jQuery code within the DOM ready function.

Comment: Curiosity: why would you migrate from already-working and fast plain JavaScript to its slow and fat framework?

Comment: do the alerts fire? If not probably haven't wrapped your code in dom ready handler

Comment: @Terry I saw it somewhere else in StackOverflow. Something about the cache & forcing it.

Comment: @Shomz, you know how it is, if we use javascript, its considered old school and bad standards. Always use JQuery all the time they push on us. At least at my current job that's what they're forcing us to do.

Comment: Ah, I understand, that's too bad... At my job we're trying to squeeze out every millisecond we can (canvas-based game), so we're going plain-JS whenever we can... See this, it's pretty cool: http://vanilla-js.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, the image src should change, but maybe it doesn't change to what you'd like. Make sure that `http://localhost/convertToReport1.do` returns exactly what you need (ideally, you can specify that in the question itself).

The page jump happens because of the anchors href attribute. Either remove it, or prevent the default anchor behaviour in your click handler function, like this:

```
$("#report1_id").click(function(e)     {   
    e.preventDefault();  // <--- this is the key, return false would also work at the end
    alert("This Is Report1");
    d = new Date();
    $("#mainImg").attr("src", "http://localhost/convertToReport1.do?"+d.getTime());
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/egvac61c/

Comment: @Terry Haha, sorry mate! :)

Comment: You're right, its right there. It should work. It has to be on the server side. But why would the same code work with the javascript code. I'll need to trace it further.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt whether using plain JS or jQ to change an image's src attribute could break the code. It has to be something else. See what your server script outputs just by opening it in the browser or try to change the src directly to some other image. That should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @LatinCanuck What happens if you don't use the query string? Could it be that your script "doesn't like it"?

Comment: Well, it finally works with the jquery code. I thought the  e.preventDefault() was what did it but then I remove it, and it still worked(albeit without the nice ajaxy feeling).

So I must have changed something on the server to make it work. No idea what though.

This is the  server code : 

response.setContentType("image/png");
WebViewer.streamImage(response, currentReport.makeReport(Report.PNG));

WebViewer is an internal library that we've been using for sometime.  I'm just happy it works. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, too bad you didn't catch what it was. You're welcome, glad you got it working in the end.